# Natural Join of two relations with more than 1 common attribute?

Tags: attributes, relational-algebra, natural-join

My actual task:
Are the following two relations equivalent, why, why not?/)

> r5: PROJECT B (R) JOIN PROJECT B (U)
>   r6: PROJECT B (R JOIN U)

[img http://s29.postimg.org/hgfgfmptx/zzz.png](http://postimg.org/image/7vvtsr0hv)

while R(ABC) and U (AB)

I've concluded that r5 will generate a relation with a single attribute B containing the common values for B which R and U share.

However I get stuck at r6. Which values of B will r6 generate? being that these two relations share 2 attributes.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are many versions of algebras depending on the exact form of their relations and operators. Give a reference or definitions for yours.

Comment: Give the definitions of the operators. Each returns a set of tuples formed from its arguments. Replace the calls by the definitions with the call arguments replaced for the definition parameters. They are the same if and only if the two expanded expressions have the same value. Alternately, you may have been given certain theorems allowing certain patterns of calls of operators to be replaced by others. Or, can you show whether r6 also must return all the B values common to R and U? (First, which does R JOIN U return; then, which from the projection of that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Natural) JOIN matches on all attributes in common (same attribute name).

In r5, B is projected on R and on U before joining. So the only attribute in common is B. (And the values in attributes A and C get ignored.)

r5 is equivalent to

```
    SELECT B
      FROM R, U
     WHERE R.B = U.B
```

In r6, the attributes in common for (R JOIN U) are B **and** A. So the result of that join has only the tuples from R and U which have the same value for **both** A and B.

r6 is equivalent to:

```
    SELECT B
      FROM R, U
     WHERE R.B = U.B AND R.A = U.A
```